# IndoorAtlas SDK example cannot run on Moverio BT 200

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run the indoorAtlasSDK example for my MoverioBT 200 glass. The example works fine for my Samsung Galaxy tab S and my nexus 4. However, I got this error when I try to run it with the glass.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IDA exception from connect() not handled
            at com.indooratlas._internal.br.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: com.indooratlas.android.IndoorAtlasException: Error in secure connection setup.
            at com.indooratlas._internal.de.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.br.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.
            at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineLoad(JDKKeyStore.java:812)
            at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:589)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.dc.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.de.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.br.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.indooratlas._internal.z$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think the problem may be related to the android version. Both my tablet and phone run android 5.0 and the glass runs 4.0.4 .The SDK is recommended for devices that run android 4.3 or higher. Please give me some suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the SDK version you used, but I'm assuming 1.3 based on the stack trace. That version requires API level 18 (Android 4.3). We released version 1.4 on April 15th with support for API levels below 18 and much improved functionality. More info at http://blog.indooratlas.com/2015/04/15/announcing-availability-of-new-indooratlas-mobile-sdks/

Comment: Thank a lot for your information, Osma. Does it mean that there is nothing I can do at the moment?. Can you tell me the day the new version will be released since I really need to use the SDK at the moment?